# rails activerecord: how to specify the inverse relationship to "belongs_to ... :class_name ..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the `belongs_to ... :class_name` association working fine, but cannot see how to create the reciprocal association.

Here's what I have now:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has fields email_id and phone_id
  belongs_to :email, :class_name => 'Rolodex' # this works fine
  belongs_to :phone, :class_name => 'Rolodex' # this works fine
end

class Rolodex < ActiveRecord::Base
  # entry:string  holds a phone#, email address, etc
  has_many :contacts    # does NOT WORK, since no Contact.rolodex_id field
end
```

And the association works fine in the Contact -> Rolodex direction (via the names :phone and :email)

```
john = Contact.first
john.phone.entry
# correctly returns the person's rolodex.entry for their phone, if any
john.email.entry
# correctly returns the person's rolodex.entry for their email, if any
```

However, if I want to lookup all the contacts who share a rolodex entry I cannot use:

```
r = Rolodex.first
r.contacts
# column contacts.rolodex_id does not exist
```

Of course, I can bypass the association and do a lookup directly:

```
Contacts.where("(email_id = ?) OR (phone_id = ?)", r.id. r.id)
```

but I assume there is some (better) way, eg, a way to specify the reciprocal of the `belongs_to ... :class_name` association ?

Comment: A very helpful site about AR associations is http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: thanks I've refered to that doc a lot of times and it does not afaik address the reciprocal to 'belongs_to ... class_name'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following would work:

```
class Rolodex < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :email_contacts, class_name: 'Contact', foreign_key: 'email_id'
  has_many :phone_contacts, class_name: 'Contact', foreign_key: 'phone_id'

  def contacts
    email_contacts + phone_contacts
  end
end
```

Comment: VERY helpful (with one correction) - foreign_key was what I was missing. As for the contacts() method, at least for rails 3.0.19, I think merge expects Hash and association is class Array, so email_contacts + phone_contacts is what works. If you agree that correction is appropriate and you'll edit it I will mark it accepted. Thanks again for the great answer.

Comment: The association is class ActiveRecord::Relation (not Array), but + may very well be right instead of merge >_>